# Codeigniter regex to match time not working

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I'm trying to use this regex `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):00:00` to match 24h format with 00 minutes and seconds.

In codeigniter's form validation rules I'm entering the regex

```
regex_match[([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):00:00]
```

and keep getting

```
Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending matching delimiter ‘)’ found
```

The regex works in php but not via CI regex rule. What am I doing wrong? :-/

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/185601/#883010 ?

Comment: Or possibly it wants a delimiter: `regex_match[/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):00:00/]` - I'm not sure, I can't find any docs for that rule

Comment: I could be wrong, but I remember reading something about the regex_pattern in the form validation that won't let you use square brackets Or character classes. The first closing bracket of the first class will end the match, thus giving the delimiter error.

Comment: yes CI doesn't support this kind of regex :( The best solution is a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the regex matcher, you could use a callback instead.

Something like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('number', 'Number', 'callback_validate_24hourtimestamp');

function validate_24hourtimestamp ($num)
{
    return preg_match('/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):00:00$/', $num);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I ended up doing